# Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW locking

Tags: mysql, hibernate, locking

Consider a Transaction, which takes a long time. During that I would like to execute few small updates on `TableSmall`, which should be executed instantly and rollback of the main Transaction shouldn't rollback those small updates.

My current problem is that these small updates will lock the `TableSmall`\ until completion of the Transaction. I need to be able to continue updating the TableSmall even when the Transaction is still running.

Is it okay to annotate the small updates with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to avoid locking rows/tables of these small updates?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation.

> Create a new transaction, suspending the current transaction if one exists.Analogous to the EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
>
> NOTE: Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-boxon all transaction managers. This in particular applies to org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager,which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to bemade available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE).
>
> A PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW scope always defines its owntransaction synchronizations. Existing synchronizations will be suspendedand resumed appropriately.

So I think if you run these small updates in only one thread instance, it should works for you like you expect.

Consider also @Transactional(propagation=NESTED) for the small tasks. This [link](https://www.resilientdatasystems.co.uk/blog/java/transactions-mis-management-how-to-kill-app/) is also interesting.

I was getting locks because in a multithread enviroment, we were calling more than one this method and then the result was that all our transactions were suspended.